# Поменять цвет label у инпутов в зависимости от value. Quasar

Tags: scss, vue3, quasar-framework

Существует проект на Vue 3 + Quasar. Необходимо при отсутствии значения в инпутах (текст, селект и тд) менять цвет лейбла. В квазаре цвет лейблов можно переопределить классом.

```
.q-field__label {
  @include text--header-4;

  color: $c-new-gray;
}
```

Таким образом для всех лейблов в проекте задан цвет и стили шрифта. Существует ли способ в SCSS менять цвет лейблов при отсутствии значения в инпутах? Возможно, какое то Quasar свойство или класс?

Существуют css селекторы типо `:valid` и так далее, но в моем случае, насколько я понял, они не очень мне подходят, так как они привязаны именно к валидации полей.

Answer (score 1):

Стоило задать вопрос, как я нашел решение. Ответ от [Berend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35593489/17349916) поражает своей простотой и лаконичностью.

В двух словах решение. [image: Классы Quasar]

На скрине выше классы Quasar для текст инпута. `q-field__native` для стилей самого инпута и `q-field__label` для стилей лейбла. Таким образом мы просто проверяем показывается ли placeholder в первом классе и в зависимости от этого задаем стиль для лейбла.

КОД

```
//label color for empty value
.q-field__native:placeholder-shown + .q-field__label {
  color: $c-new-gray--darkest;
}
```